# How to choose desktop images from a theme?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, themes

I'm using theme Windows Classic to get rid of the aero effect (for the sake of speed for my developing works) but I enjoy having the background images/photos from the other themes (e.g. Bing Best) but I don't know how to do this after trying a while in the desktop personalizing settings of Windows 7.
Please help if you know how to do it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you switched to Window Classic Theme, you still can use Windows Theme's background image.

Personalization > Desktop Background > Choose Windows Desktop Backgrounds from Picture Location drop down. you'll see the background images of the Windows Theme you'd installed .

for your case, the downloaded themes are installed under `C:\Users\ <username> \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\` and browser that folder and choose image as u want

[image]

and if you choose multiple images, these will change automatically according to the time you've set. like automatic window background changer.